# PHP: Create string of dynamic variables

Tags: php, shopping-cart, dynamic-variables

I need to create dynamic variables for a shopping cart to send to a payment gateway.

Each variable is in the form:

```
$parameters['Product Name: Qty = '. $cart_qty] = $subtotal;
```

So, if I order two products the list of parameters would be:

```
$parameters['Product1: Qty = 2'] = 24.00;

$parameters['Product2: Qty = 3'] = 60.00;
```

...and so on.

How would I generate these parameters as a string by looping through each product?

Such as:

```
while ($data_cart = mysql_fetch_array($result_cart)) {
    $prodName = $data_product['prodName'];
    $unitPrice = number_format((float)$data_product['priceRetail'], 2, '.', '');
    $cart_qty = $data_cart['qty'];
    $subtotal = $cart_qty * $unitPrice;

    $parameter .= ??? // <-- How to create a dynamic string here to output later

}
```

And then how would I write it to the page later, echo or print?

Comment: Do you know what format you expect to output? e.g. a long string, html table, markdown table & etc.

Comment: Here is a sample of current parameters:

 $parameters['receipt_address'] = $email;

 $parameters['gst_rate'] = '10';

 $parameters['gst_added'] = 'TRUE';

 $parameters['Freight'] = $freight;

 $parameters['Order# '.$orderID.' Total Price'] = $priceTotal;


I need to create these dynamically (into a string presumably) in an earlier loop and then output then like the above at the bottom of the page. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a query building function like `http_build_query()`, after building a full array *(your keys have a quote issue though, based on your example)*:

```
<?php
$parameters['Product1: Qty = 1'] = '24.00';
$parameters['Product3: Qty = 3'] = '24.00';
$parameters['Product2: Qty = 5'] = '24.00';
$parameters['Product5: Qty = 1'] = '24.00';

echo http_build_query($parameters);
?>
```

Gives you:

```
Product1%3A+Qty+%3D+1=24.00&Product3%3A+Qty+%3D+3=24.00&Product2%3A+Qty+%3D+5=24.00&Product5%3A+Qty+%3D+1=24.00
```

Comment: Thanks, @Rasclatt. These need to be generated through a loop and accumulated into the variable '$parameter'; Your further assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: So you are able to compile an array using this in a loop? `$parameters['Order# '.$orderID.' Total Price'] = $priceTotal;`